# Automating Adobe CQ5 web based application using Selenium Web driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to automate Adobe CQ5 web based application using Selenium Web driver. Is it feasible to automate this application? As this applications is basically designed by the BA guys by selecting the standard templates and design the page by drag and drop the components from sidekick and provide the properties for the components. Then activate the designed page. Once the page is activated the user can publish the page. Any suggestions please!!

How to create a wrapper methods for Mouse Right Click, Double Click, Context Menu options like New, Open, Save, Delete? Similarly I have 5 popup windows where the user clicks OK button. Locator ID for OK button keeps changing every time we refresh the page. Hence the script is not able to identify the OK button. We are working on a workaround to click the OK button to save the Content Paragraph component. Moreover, the main observation is that each component behavior and identification properties are unique.

Any solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a look at how pages are created using Adobe CQ5 from a video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKZuIk-hUec), and I think Selenium should be able to handle automating this, or in other words, you can automate the web page creation (and adding other controls) using Selenium.

> Is it feasible to automate this application?

I think so. Since it is a web page application, I think you should have no issues automating this using Selenium.

> How to create a wrapper methods for Mouse Right Click, Double Click, Context Menu options like New, Open, Save, Delete

You would need to explore the API for the selected language that you choose. Selenium gives you the freedom of having your test designed independently of how it has been developed. It doesn't matter your website is designed using CQ5, Java, PHP. You can use Java written Selenium script to test the CQ5 application. No headaches there.

> Locator ID for OK button keeps changing every time we refresh the page.

Selenium provides you several other methods to recognize a web element (using XPaths, CSS, Name, Link Text) etc, so you can choose another mechanism which suits you the best.